# laravel print the validation error message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I read the official page about validation in laravel  http://laravel.com/docs/validation#working-with-error-messages and I followed them. So my code is

```
 $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Restaurant::$rules);

        if ($validation->passes())
        {
            Restaurant::create($input);

            return Redirect::route('users.index');
        }
        else{
            $messages = $validation->messages();
            foreach ($messages->all() as $message)
            {
                echo $message + "</br>";
            }
        }
```

I can see the error message but it is just `00`. Is there a better way to know in which form's field the error is and what is the error description?

I already have `rules` and I now the input is breaking the rules but I need to read the error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 $messages = $validation->messages();

            foreach ($messages->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message)
            {
                echo $message;
            }
```

[Official Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#working-with-error-messages)

> After calling the messages method on a Validator instance, you will receive a MessageBag instance, which has a variety of convenient methods for working with error messages.

According to the [MessageBag documentation](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.MessageBag.html) the function **all** Get all of the messages for every key in the bag.

Answer (score 1):

You can access errors through the `errors()` object, and loop through the all rules' keys.

Something like this:

```
Route::get('error', function(){

    $inputs = array(
        'id'        => 5,
        'parentID'  => 'string',
        'title'     => 'abc',
    );

    $rules = array(
        'id'        => 'required|integer',
        'parentID'  => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'title'     => 'required|min:5',
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);

    if($validation->passes()) {
        return 'passed!';
    } else {
        $errors = $validation->errors(); //here's the magic
        $out = '';
        foreach($rules as $key => $value) {
            if($errors->has($key)) { //checks whether that input has an error.
                $out.= '<p>'$key.' field has this error:'.$errors->first($key).'</p>'; //echo out the first error of that input
            }
        }

        return $out;
    }

});
```